# Will journal be lost if there is no time to flush to the journal writer before jvm hangs?

Tags: alluxio

Many journals are written asynchronously to the related journal writer through AsyncJournalWriter. If the journal is in `AsyncJournalWriter.mQueue` but there is no time to flush to the journal writer before jvm hangs, will the journal be lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operation is finished and journal is written to local journal before returning success to client. so if jvm hangs, client will take a longer time to receive the operation succeed results because it needs to wait for the journal written.